# How to get an email sent from only the last row of my form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am very new to coding and I can't figuer out what I am doing wrong. I need 1 email sent from the last entry in my form. So as the students submit their pre-test they get an email that contains the result of their pre-test.
This is what my code looks like:

```
function sendEmails() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
      // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 3, numRows, 1)
      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[1];  // Second column
      var message = row[2];       // Third column
      var subject = "Résultat de formatif";

      // This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
     var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
     var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
     var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
     Logger.log(lastCell.getValue());


    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make this a [mcve], please! <3

Comment: Assuming this is about Google Spreadsheets - adding a tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

I do that by:

- adding a separate column "STATUS" to the sheet
- in your email sending function iterate over rows and act only on rows with "STATUS" being blank
- after successfully sending email for a row, put something to the "STATUS" column

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [event object documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit).

You can [install a "trigger"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to automatically run your script on every form submission. Because this is triggered per submission, you don't need to worry about trying to find the last row or if the email had already been sent.

```
function sendEmails(formResponse) {
  var answers = formResponse.values;
  var emailAddress = answers[1];  // Second column
  var message = answers[2];       // Third column
  var subject = "Résultat de formatif";

  // This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
  var range = formResponse.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getLastColumn();

  try {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Did not send email to " + emailAddress + ". See error: " + e);
    range.getSheet().getRange(row, column+1).setValue("EMAIL NOT SENT");
    return;
  } 
  range.getSheet().getRange(row, column+1).setValue("EMAIL SENT");
}
```

[image]